# Gdal RasterIO error about Too few parameters

Tags: gdal, c++, rasterio

I want to get the value using GDAL RasterIO in C++, there is my code. howveer there is a bug that `error C2660: “GDALDataset::RasterIO”` and there are too few 
parameters

```
            GDALRasterBand* poRasterBand;  
            poRasterBand = pDataset->GetRasterBand(1); 
            int nXsize = poRasterBand->GetXSize();  
            int nYsize = poRasterBand->GetYSize();  
            int xSize=1;
            int ySize=1;
            GDALDataType dataType =poRasterBand->GetRasterDataType();  
            float *pBuf = new float[nYsize * nXsize];  

            pDataset->RasterIO(GF_Read, 0, 0, nXsize, nYsize, pBuf, nXsize,nYsize, dataType, 0, 0);  
            std::cout<<pBuf<<std::endl;
            delete[] pBuf;
            std::cin.get();  
            std::cin.get();  
            return 0;
```

Comment: My GDALDataset::RasterIO lines end with 1,NULL,0,0,0); which is *band count, band map, nPixelSpace, nLineSpace, nBandSpace*. The example http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html reads from the band, try reading from a raster band (change pDataset to poRasterBand), it's a bit easier as these args are not needed which is probably where you're getting confused between GDALDataset::RasterIO http://www.gdal.org/classGDALDataset.html#a80d005ed10aefafa8a55dc539c2f69da and GDALRasterBand::RasterIO http://www.gdal.org/classGDALRasterBand.html#a30786c81246455321e96d73047b8edf1

Comment: @MichaelStimson  thank you very much！ you are great !

Comment: @MichaelStimson would you mind tell me that how to get values from `pBuf` . The `std::cout<<pBuf<<std::endl;`  didnt work

Comment: I want to read values from it and save as  2*D arrary. but the `pBuf` all is zero.

Comment: I'm not sure about 2d array in C++, the pBuf is a 1D array of float, you just need to work out how many rows and columns: LocationInArray = (nXsize * ThisRow) + ThisCol; if (ThisCol, ThisRow) is the cell you want to get the value for. Note that generally rows start from the top and increase *down* but cols start from the left and increase *to the right*.

Comment: @MichaelStimson thank you for your help.  I have slove the problem and `LocationInArray = (nXsize * ThisRow) + ThisCol` should be `LocationInArray = (nXsize * (ThisRow-1)) + ThisCol -1`

Comment: That is true if you're using 1 based indexing, if it works for you with a negative 1 offset that's great; the line supplied is from a working C++ program with a 0 based index. Now that it's working can you please answer your own question, with a working code snippet, for the benefit of future users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @Michael Stimson's answer!

The problem is that `GDALDataset::RasterIO` and `GDALRasterBand::RasterIO` is different. there is some introduction about them.

http://www.gdal.org/classGDALDataset.html#a80d005ed10aefafa8a55dc539c2f69da
http://www.gdal.org/classGDALRasterBand.html#a30786c81246455321e96d73047b8edf1

There is my new code.

```
GDALRasterBand* poRasterBand;  
poRasterBand = pDataset->GetRasterBand(1);   
int nXsize = poRasterBand->GetXSize();  
int nYsize = poRasterBand->GetYSize();  

GDALDataType dataType =poRasterBand->GetRasterDataType();  
float *pBuf = new float[nYsize * nXsize];  

poRasterBand->RasterIO(GF_Read, 0, 0, nXsize, nYsize, pBuf, nXsize,nYsize, dataType, 0, 0);  
int LocationInArray = (nXsize * (Yline-1)) + Xpixel -1;
std::cout<<*(pBuf+LocationInArray)<<std::endl;
```